# One off 'share' on facebook button

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, social-networking, facebook-social-plugins

I am building a simple online game which I would like users to be prompted to share their score on facebook when they complete the game. I don't really want to complicate the UI too much and ideally would like it to work similar to twitter's tweet button and have a predefined (editable) message like:

"I have just scored 560 on mygame.com"

I would like this to get posted onto the user's facebook wall.

What is the easiest option for code and for user? I'm working in php, mysql, jquery, javascript, ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest you use the Javascript SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID - get one at https://developers.facebook.com/apps/
      channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here - Change fields below to match what you want to share and wrap it inside a function that you trigger on click
    FB.ui({
      method: 'feed',
      name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
      link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
      picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
      caption: 'Reference Documentation',
      description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.'
    },function(response) {
      if (response && response.post_id) {
        alert('Post was published.');
      } else {
        alert('Post was not published.');
      }
    });
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>
```

The channel file can be just:

```
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the Facebook Javascript SDK at hand, you can build a button linking to `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=393236134020452&link=<the url you want to share>&picture=<url of any picture you want to show in the users' status updates>&name=<title of the status update>&caption=<text of the status update>&redirect_uri=<url to redirect users upon completion of the sharing action>`, possibly in a new tab.

I made something similar [here](http://raibaz.github.com/wrltzr) using pure JS and the JS SDK, if you want to have a look.

Comment: (Note that the sharer opened by this dialog allows user to insert their own messages as well)

Answer (score 0):

```
    $attachment = array(
     'access_token' => $accessToken,
     'message' => $text,
     'name' => $appName,
     'link' => $appLink,
     'description' => "I have just scored 560 on mygame.com",
    );
    return $response = $facebook->api("/$fbid/feed", 'POST', $attachment);
```

Where $facebook is Facebook API object. You have to create facebook app and permission to post on user's wall.